# Python Regular Expressions in PHP 

Tags: php, python

What would be the PHP equivalent to this code, I have tried curl but am unable to get it to work

```
import urllib2,urllib,re

url=' Delete me'

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3 Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
link=lemon.read()
response.close()
match=re.compile('Delete me 2').findall(link)
print match
```

Ok my code now looks like this

```
<?php

 $url = "url";
 $homepage = file_get_contents($url);
 print $homepage
?>
```

in python I would now find the strings I need using something like this

```
match=re.compile('src="(.+?)" border="0" /></td>\n <td class="namewidth"><a title=".+?" href="(.+?)">(.+?)</a>').findall(link)
```

(.+?) being the unknown what is the equivalent to this in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you just tried file_get_contents()? It doesn't have the power of curl but if you just need to pull a URL it works.

Comment: Thank's that work great! Now I just need to read upon php regular expressions to try to filter the data i need.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. If this was the answer you needed please mark it as answered and up vote it.